# A Problem dealing with Cache memory on a computer

Tags: computer-architecture, cache

This is Problem 13-3 from the book "Logic and Computer Design Fundamentals" by M. Morris Mano and Charles R. Kime. I believe I have the answer right for part *a* and part *b*. That is, they match the website. However, the website is for the 5th edition of the book and I am using the 4th edition.

Problem:

A computer has a 32-bit address and a direct-mapping cache. Addressing is to the byte level. The cache has a capacity of 1 KB and uses lines that are 32 bytes. It uses write-through and so does not require a dirty bit.
(a) How many bits are in index for the cache?
(b) How many bits are in the tag for the cache?
(c) What is the total number of bits of storage in the cache, including the valid bits, the tags and the cache lines?

My answers:

(a) The number of lines (or blocks) in the cache is 1024/32 or 32. Hence the size of the index in the cache is 5.

(b) We need 5 bits to specify the location in the block. Let \$t\$ be the number of bits we need to specify the tag. This gives us the following equation:
$$ w + 5 + 5 = 32 $$
Hence \$w = 22\$.

(c) The size of the cache memory is \$1024 * 8\$ or \$8192\$ bits. Now for each line (or block) we need \$5\$ bits for the tag and \$22\$ bits for the index. We also need \$1\$ bit for each block to verify that the block is valid. \$M\$ is the number of bits needed for the entire cache.
$$ M = 8192 + 32 ( 5 + 22 + 1 ) = 8192 + 32(28) = 9088 $$

However, the 5th edition of the book reads:
$$ 32 × (32 × 8 + 22 + 1) = 8928 \, bits$$

It looks like to me they are not allocating space in the cache for the tag. I believe you have to store the tag. Am I wrong about that?

Updated Answer:

Given that a block is in a particular part of the cache, we know 5 bits of the
address. Hence we do not have to store those 5 bits. Hence the answer is:
$$ M = 8192 + 32 ( 22 + 1 ) = 8192 + 32(23) = 8928 $$
Is my reasoning right?